# PHPIZE error when trying to install intl with pecl

Tags: xampp, magento2, php-extension, pecl

So, for magento2 i need to install : PHP Extension intl.

Now after looking up i'm trying to do this but i keep getting errros. I'm on a MAC and i'm using XAMPP, too bad when i run 'sudo pecl install int' i get the following error.

```
Starting to download intl-3.0.0.tgz (248,200 bytes)
.....done: 248,200 bytes
150 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20170718
Zend Module Api No:      20170718  
Zend Extension Api No:   320170718
autom4te: need GNU m4 1.4 or later: /usr/bin/m4
ERROR: `phpize' failed
```

I also tried using 'sudo pecl update-channels' But that gives me the following messages:

```
Updating channel "doc.php.net"
Channel "doc.php.net" is not responding over http://, failed with message: File http://doc.php.net:80/channel.xml not valid (redirected but no location)
Trying channel "doc.php.net" over https:// instead
Cannot retrieve channel.xml for channel "doc.php.net" (Connection to `ssl://doc.php.net:443' failed: Connection refused)
Updating channel "pear.php.net"
Channel "pear.php.net" is up to date
Updating channel "pear.phpunit.de"
Channel "pear.phpunit.de" is not responding over http://, failed with message: File http://pear.phpunit.de:80/channel.xml not valid (received: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
)
Trying channel "pear.phpunit.de" over https:// instead
Cannot retrieve channel.xml for channel "pear.phpunit.de" (Connection to `ssl://pear.phpunit.de:443' failed: )
Updating channel "pear.symfony-project.com"
Channel "pear.symfony-project.com" is up to date
Updating channel "pecl.php.net"
Channel "pecl.php.net" is up to date
```

What can i do to solve this? I'm using XAMPP with PHP 7.2